# Android - an app to disable facebook push notification

Tags: android, push-notification

Is it possible to create an app that it's sole purpose is to toggle on/off the facebook push notifications? (like a silence for facebook)?

Comment: I just tried to google but couldn't find anything. My question is pretty much if its possible? (security wise it sounds like my app should not have permission to block facebook's push nots).

Answer (score 0):

If you give your app notification-access permissions you should be able to dismiss the notifications as soon as they pop-up, but the user will still get notified (sound or vibrating), although he won't see the notification when the device is unlocked as your app would have dismissed it.

Pushbullet does that.

In any case it's no use, the user can go to the Facebook app details and uncheck the notifications box.